# Complex series sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that for $|z|<1$, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{z}{1-z}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n z^{2^n}}{1+z^{2^n}}=\frac{z}{1-z}$$
As a hint is given to use the dyadic expansion of an integer.
I have no idea how to proceed.Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978266/show-sum-n-fracz2n1-z2n1-fracz1-z

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788932/find-the-value-of-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-0n-fracx2k1-x2k1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628569/prove-that-sum-n-0-infty-fracz2n1-z2n1-fracz1-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{k2^{n+1}} \\&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{2^n+k2^{n+1}} \\&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{2^n(1+2k)}
\end{align}$$
Now apply your hint, which can be worded as

> Every integer $k\geqslant1$ can be written in one and only one way as $k=2^n+i2^{n+1}=2^n(1+2i)$, for some $n\geqslant0$ and $i\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS of the first is
\begin{align}
&(z+z^3+z^5+z^7+\cdots)\\
&+(z^2+z^6+z^{10}+z^{14}+\cdots)\\
&+(z^4+z^{12}+z^{20}+z^{28}+\cdots)+\cdots.
\end{align}

The LHS of the second is
\begin{align}
&(z-z^2+z^3-z^4+z^5-\cdots)\\
&+(2z^2-2z^4+2z^6-2z^8+2z^{10}-\cdots)\\
&+(4z^4-4z^8+4z^{12}-4z^{16}+4z^{20}-\cdots)+\cdots.
\end{align}

Do these give a clue?

Comment: Yes,i can understand by expanding the first few terms explicitly,but i have no idea how to write it formally.

Comment: @AnwitaBhowmik It shows that the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$ is of importance.

Comment: Sorry,could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

"*Any positive integer has a unique representation in base $2$*" leads to
$$ \prod_{k\geq 0}\left(1+z^{2^k}\right) = 1+z+z^2+z^3+\ldots = \frac{1}{1-z} \tag{A}$$
and by applying $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides we get:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{2^k z^{2^k-1}}{z^{2^k}+1} = \frac{1}{1-z}\tag{B}$$
proving your second identity. The first identity has already been proved by Brevan Ellefsen: it is a consequence of "*Any positive integer can be written in a unique way as the product between an odd integer and a power of $2$*".